# Random Number Generator issue in C#

Tags: c#, random, numbers

Well after a long time, I managed to get the out comes from my program I asked about in my first question. It add a random number to a list to be used as a ID number and then exports it to Excel. However I came across a probelm when using more than 2 data members in my datafile: The Random numbers i generate double up, causing my program to crash.

```
static Dictionary<string,Backup> getData()
{

    Dictionary<string, Backup> bDict = new Dictionary<string, Backup>();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/data/storedata.txt");

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {

        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        string[] parts = line.Split(' ');

        string item = parts[0];
        string owner = parts[1];

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int test = rnd.Next(item.Length+10000);//For every 'item' a Random number is generated.(the +10000 is simply to produce a 4-digit number)

        //Console.WriteLine(test);//Testing 
        Backup BP = new Backup(item, owner,test);

        bDict.Add(test.ToString(), BP);//Adding to the Dictionary.

        //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", item, test, owner));

    }
    return bDict;
}//Read file, Grabed data and stored it in a List.
```

What i'm after/trying to do is have a sort of check, that if two numbers are the same a new number is generated as a replacement(or some other way of doing the same thing). I've tried if statements but VS keeps asking if i meant to compare to something else. I've looked at things here on Stackoverflow, but the answers don't fit what is happening with my code.
Any Help be appreciated.

FAQ
datafile will have upwards of 500 'items'
no min/max

cheers

Comment: I find it hard to believe you couldn't find another example on SO, this question is so frequent it's almost eligible for the FAQ. Typing your question header into the "Ask a Question" area yields lots of possible answers already on SO.

Comment: [Revisiting randomness](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness.aspx)

Comment: I guess in this instance panic set in. The statements within the loop hardly run quickly given all the io operations (especially if uncommented). That would cause the random number to change a bit. If the loop were tighter then it would have been clearer to the OP.

Comment: Random numbers are not unique. Use a GUID.

Answer (score 5):

> The Random numbers i generate double up, causing my program to crash.

You have to reuse the same random instance, so create it outside the loop, otherwise it's seeded with he same time causing the same numbers.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx):

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same
>   seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated.

Apart from that you have to check if the number already exists in the `Dictionary`:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
// ...

while(bDict.ContainsKey(test.ToString()))
    test = rnd.Next(item.Length + 10000);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that also solves the NEXT problem he will have.

Comment: Indeed and +1, although the OP will encounter a final problem: why does the algorithm get slower and slower before eventually grinding to a halt?

Comment: Thanks For the Help, simple thing i should of known. This part will help out greatly.

Answer (score 4):

As a start, you'll want to move the `Random` object initialisation *outside* the `while` loop.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)....
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated. One way to produce different sequences is to make the seed value time-dependent, thereby producing a different series with each new instance of Random. By default, the parameterless constructor of the Random class uses the system clock to generate its seed value

Which is basically meaning: initiate it too quickly (i.e, in a `loop` of some kind) and you'll likely get the same value.

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate `rnd` outside the while loop. Then you'll give the random number chance to behave correctly. What you are doing is causing the generator to reinitialise; ruining the statistical properties of the generator.

**But, for your specific problem, I wouldn't use `rnd` at all.** The reason being that you don't want any duplicate random numbers. Drawing a random number and then testing if it's already been drawn is inefficient and gets *increasingly* inefficient in time (and, by the way, also ruins the statistical properties of the generator: although the expected mean will remain correct, the expected variance will increase beyond 1 / 12 and higher moments will be incorrect).

If you don't really need your sequence to be particularly random (i.e. don't care that the expected value of the mean is 0.5 etc.) then you can develop a function that exchanges various bits in an integer in a well-defined manner. Use the output of that function having fed consecutive numbers to it as your sequence.